# Using Karate, I am trying to match two json arrays which are out of order

Tags: karate

for e.g.

```
* def products = [{"ProductCode":"a","UnitPrice":100.0},{ {"ProductCode":"b","UnitPrice":200.0}]

* def inventory = [{"ProductCode":"b","UnitPrice":200.0},{ {"ProductCode":"a","UnitPrice":100.0}]

* match products == inventory
```

This fails as the order of elements in the array are not matching. How can I tell karate to ignore the order?

Answer (score 4):

You really really should read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains

```
* def products = [{"ProductCode":"a","UnitPrice":100.0},{"ProductCode":"b","UnitPrice":200.0}]
* def inventory = [{"ProductCode":"b","UnitPrice":200.0},{"ProductCode":"a","UnitPrice":100.0}]
* match products contains only inventory
```

Answer (score 0):

> The match operation is smart because white-space does not matter, and *the order of keys (or data elements) does not matter*. Karate is even able to ignore fields you choose - which is very useful when you want to handle server-side dynamically generated fields such as UUID-s, time-stamps, security-tokens and the like.

> *The match syntax involves a double-equals sign '=='* to represent a comparison (and not an assignment '=').

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).